# Node Js what in your world and/or mine

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok. For a very long time now I have been trying to figure out just one thing but can't seem to grasp it. Please, someone. What is node JS used for? This google snippet.....

> Node. js is primarily used for non-blocking, event-driven servers, due to its single-threaded nature. It's used for traditional web sites and back-end API services, but was designed with real-time, push-based architectures in mind.

is a tad confusing. Anyone willing to break that statement down for me? I read things like how node js allows the ability to execute javascript code but doesn't the normal web browser do that already? Or how it allows you to host static files but doesn't my cPanel already do that?

Just simply, what in the world is node js used/best used for??

And yes, I'm aware that this had been asked more times than one could think. I just need an answer from someone in this time frame, not from an answer posted 8 years ago.

Comment: It is a serverside. You are not running the server in your browser.

Comment: Node.js allow you to write normal (non-browser) code. You can implement your own cpanel (maybe you want to call it npanel or WBRpanel) in node.js instead of PHP. Node.js is used to run javascript outside of the web browser the same way you can run PHP or Ruby or Java or Python or C++ or Go etc.

Comment: An answer from 8 years ago will still provide the relevant information. In short, JS is a programming language, and in connection with the browser's DOM and APIs like `navigator` and `fetch` you can do the things you need to do in the context of the browser displaying an HTML document. NodeJS is a way to run JS code outside the browser, which also means using different APIs. There's no `document` for instance, but there's `fs`, which allows to access files on the hard drive. You also have network capabilites, so you can use it to write a backend instead of, say, PHP.

Comment: As for why would you want to run javascript outside of the browser? Well, some people like myself simply think javascript is really good programming language

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at their official website for a clear answer: https://nodejs.org/.

If you are still confused, basically Node.js is a JavaScript environment.  It allows you to install packages, and run applications SERVER-SIDE.

Every Node.js project has a `package.json` file which specifies all packages and scripts used in the project.

To create a `package.json` file and a Node.js project, download node.js with the link I provided above, create a directory and navigate to it, and run:

`npm init`.

You can just keep pressing enter and use the default options. With a `package.json` file created you can now create a server-side web application with Express.js or some other framework that can run in the browser using the `node {whatever your javascript file name is}.js` command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is true, but NPM and the NPM CLI comes with the Node.js download. But I guess you are right. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> non-blocking, event-driven servers,  due to its single-threaded nature

So Node.JS runs things like network and file system requests concurrently with code execution so they're "non-blocking" ie don't halt code execution. It manages this by executing these requests in a separate worker-pool of threads then triggering events/callback functions. This means that it simplifies development as it allows one to develop without the complexities of manually managing multiple threads whilst still maintaining great performance characteristics.

Node.JS is used primarily as a server-side technology however it can also be used to develop CLI applications. Yes the browser can execute JavaScript however it cannot run it on the server. Yes cPanel lets you host static files however NodeJS can allow you to run more complex tasks on said files, load data from databases, manipulate said data etc.

> What's is best used for?

Rapid development for web based application back ends and CLI applications which have good performance characteristics.